# Why do my CSS changes, even when importantified, have no effect?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

In trying to fine-tune the appearance of my Web API page, I'm making changes to CSS classes, and adding new classes, to \Content/Site.css, yet they do not alter the appearance of the page as they should, even when I append "!important" to specific rules.

For example, I added a horizontal rule to the page, which does show up, but quite unobtrusively (with a faint, barely discernible line). So I added this .css class to Site.css:

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    color: navy;
    background: #333;
}
```

...which works just fine in another project, but doesn't in this one. The line remains faint even when I append "! important" to the "height" rule there:

```
height: 1px !important;
```

I tried right-clicking the page at runtime and selecting "Reload Page" but that made no difference, either.

Other CSS changes (margins and paddings) are not having any effect, either; this is just one specific case whose resolution should work for all of them.

What do I need to do to get modified/added CSS rules to be applied?

### UPDATE

Even when I, acquiescing to Algernop K's suggestion, change the code from this:

```
. . .
builder.Append(string.Format("<h1 style=\'margin-left:16\'>Available PRO*ACT Reports for <span style='color: #000080;'>{0}</span></h1>", _unit.ToUpper()));

builder.Append("<p style='margin-left:16;'>(Click any link below to download the Excel spreadsheet file to your computer)</p>");
builder.Append("</div>");

builder.Append("<div class=\"row\">");
builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-12\">");
builder.Append("<hr />");
. . .
```

...to this:

```
. . .
builder.Append(string.Format("<h1 style=\'margin-left:16; margin-top:48;\'>Available PRO*ACT Reports for <span style='color: #000080;'>{0}</span></h1>", _unit.ToUpper()));

builder.Append("<p style='margin-left:16;'>(Click any link below to download the Excel spreadsheet file to your computer)</p>");
builder.Append("</div>");

builder.Append("<div class=\"row\">");
builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-12\">");
builder.Append("<hr style=\'size:4;\' />");
. . .
```

...(adding "; margin-top:48;" to the h1 element, and "size" to the hr), no change is evident.

### UPDATE 2

A "funny" thing happened on the way to the Inspecting of Elements. As Chris W suggested, I right-clicked the hr element on the page, but it's so miniscule that I may have got a different element to inspect. Nevertheless, an err msg in the console may be revealing the basic problem - there it says, "*bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery*"

### UPDATE 3

Should I explicitly add my \Content\Site.css file to the html? I tried dragging it from Solution Explorer below the lines shown above, hoping it would generate the correct code, but instead it gave me:

```
C:\Projects\ProActWebReports\ProActWebReports\Content\Site.css
```

...and a prompt to add "'System.Security.Policy.Site' and all other references in file"

Note that I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260191/what-jquery-references-need-to-be-added-for-bootstrap-to-work-right-and-where)

### UPDATE 4

FWIW, here's the entire (relevant) code that builds up this html:

```
namespace PlatypusWebReports.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class LandingPageController : ApiController
    {
        private string _unit;

        [Route("{unit}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string unit)
        {
            _unit = unit;
            string beginningHtml = GetBeginningHTML();
            string deliveryPerformanceHtml = GetDeliveryPerformanceHTML();
            string fillRateHtml = GetFillRateHTML();
            string priceComplianceHtml = GetPriceComplianceHTML();
            string produceUsageHtml = GetProduceUsageHTML();
            string endingHtml = GetEndingHTML();
            String HtmlToDisplay = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}",
                beginningHtml,
                deliveryPerformanceHtml,
                fillRateHtml,
                priceComplianceHtml,
                produceUsageHtml,
                endingHtml);

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(
                    HtmlToDisplay,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "text/html"
                )
            };
        }

        private string GetBeginningHTML()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("<html>");
            builder.Append("<head>");
            builder.Append("<title>");
            builder.Append(string.Format("Available Reports For {0}", _unit));
            builder.Append(_unit);
            builder.Append("</title>");            
            builder.Append("<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js' integrity='sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>");
            builder.Append("<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />");
            builder.Append("<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>");
            builder.Append("</head>");
            builder.Append("<body class=\"body-content\" style='margin-top:0;margin-left:60;margin-right:60;'>");

            builder.Append("<div class=\"jumbotronjr\">");
            builder.Append("<img src=\"http://www.Platypususa.com/wp-content/themes/Platypus/images/pa_logo_notag.png\" alt=\"Platypus logo\">");
            builder.Append(string.Format("<h1 style=\'margin-left:16; margin-top:48;\'>Available Platypus Reports for <span style='color: #000080;'>{0}</span></h1>", _unit.ToUpper()));

            builder.Append("<p style='margin-left:16;'>(Click any link below to download the Excel spreadsheet file to your computer)</p>");
            builder.Append("</div>");

            builder.Append("<div class=\"row\">");
            builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-12\">");
            builder.Append("<hr style='color:red;height:12;' />");
            builder.Append("</div>");
            builder.Append("</div>");
            // for beginning the row div
            builder.Append("<div class=\"row\">");

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        private string GetEndingHTML()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            // for ending the row div
            builder.Append("</div>");
            builder.Append("</body>");
            builder.Append("</html>");
            return builder.ToString();
        }
        . . .
```

Everything is displaying basically as I want it to, it's just not allowing me to add the "gingebread" (adding margins, hrs, shadow around the used area)

### UPDATE 5

Even though _ViewStart.cshtml points to Layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

...and _Layout.cshtml renders (supposedly) the Styles in the Content/css folder, which contains the Sites.css which I have been adding CSS styles madly to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - PRO*ACT USA</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

...all that does nothing to add these styles I want. The only way seems to use inline styles:

```
builder.Append("<body style='margin-top:40;margin-left:60;margin-right:60;'>");
. . .            
builder.Append("<hr style='border:0;height:1;background:#333;color:navy;' />");
```

The whole process could certainly be made much clea[n,r]er / more straightforward.

Comment: Have you tried changing it inline with `size`?

Comment: Okay, I will, but I also know that that is considered "uncool" - even uncooler than using "!important" probably.

Comment: Right click it, choose "inspect element" and look at the inheritance to discover what may be overriding your implicit values.

Comment: are you using any external css? eg.bootstrap etc.

Comment: Yes, it's bootstrapified; but so is the other project where the same code is working fine.

Comment: the order of the css file matters and in this case, bootstrapified is the latest and so this gets the precedence. Add your custom style after the 3rd party css is loaded

Comment: @KarthikMR: This doesn't explain why adding the styles inline doesn't work, does it?

Comment: even if you add inline style, if any other css is loaded after that and even if that css has !important then that will be applied.

Comment: It is uncool indeed, but mostly fine for single elements. Did you ensure the problem isn't with CSS caching or such? I know another cheap trick, and that is to add a `border-bottom` or similar to your `hr` in `CSS`.

Comment: @AlgernopK.: Appended the following to the hr CSS, but made no difference: border-bottom: 4px;

Comment: @B.ClayShannon There are [lots of examples](https://codepen.io/ibrahimjabbari/pen/ozinB) of styling `hr` with borders though, it should work. Try giving it a colour

Comment: I am - navy, but it's so faint I can't tell whether it's navy, navybean, or wavy gravy.

Comment: Phrases like "but that made no difference" and "not having any effect" does not sufficiently describe what your expected results are. They only point out that the expected results were not obtained. Can you elaborate more on what was created with your updates and what you intended to create?

Comment: Also, double check your CSS syntax. An early CSS error may cause the browser to ignore subsequent CSS definitions.

Comment: I want the hr to stand out more - to be "taller" so that it is more readily visible. As it is, it is very faint and barely noticeable. By "made no difference," I mean exactly that.

Comment: @JohnH: I added the entire Site.css file to csslint.net, and it found no errors.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you using Razor or not? It looks like you're building all the HTML as a string (which makes me want to cry, FWIW), but then you talk about `_ViewStart` and your layout, which don't seem to ever come into play at all here.

Comment: How else can I build it to pass back to an AJAX call? And yes, apparently _ViewStart and _Layout are not being used, but I thought they would be automatically/by default. Anyway, I got it all working by adding inline styles to the dynamically generated html (as string).