# What jQuery references need to be added for Bootstrap to work right, and where?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, src

I've been struggling with bootstrap and custom CSS not coexisting well (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259361/why-do-my-css-changes-even-when-importantified-have-no-effect))

I saw that I was getting "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" and so, based on what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658015/bootstrap-wont-detect-jquery-1-11-0-uncaught-error-bootstraps-javascript-re) (Sridhar's accepted answer), I changed this:

```
builder.Append("<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />");
builder.Append("<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>");
builder.Append("<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js\" integrity=\"sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>");
```

...around to this:

```
builder.Append("<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js\" integrity=\"sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>");
builder.Append("<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />");
builder.Append("<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>");
```

...but it makes no difference.

Just what do I need to do to get Bootstrap to realize I *am* referencing jQuery?

### UPDATE

I changed the quotes from double to single and removed the backwhacks so the jquery reference is now this:

```
builder.Append("<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js' integrity='sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>");
```

...but it makes no difference.

### UPDATE 2

Even when I add an inline style like this:

```
builder.Append("<hr style='color:red;height:12;' />");
```

...it doesn't change the wimpy (barely visible) horizontal rule.

Comment: I need to ask: Why does you "src" has some bars?
--- builder.Append("<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js\" integrity=\"sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>"); ---

Isn't that the problem on call "jQuery"?

Comment: Do you mean the escape character ("\"), or...???

Comment: Yup, in <script> after src=\"..." There is a bar. Shouldn't be only text inside quotes? I ask you cause i'm also new in this kind of stuff. So it's weird to me see those "\" "/" outside quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but I removed the backwhacks and it makes no difference.

Comment: Not sure how Update 2 is related to your issue but you need to change the border-top css property to adjust the <hr>...